Question based on roots of unity
I have issue in these questions where we have to find$$\sum_{z^5=1\atop z\ne1}\frac z{1+z^2}.$$
My method was to write $\frac z{1+z^2}$ in Euler form and then simplify it to result into summation of $1/\cos(\arg z)$.
Then I assumed an equation $\cos(5x)=1$ and simplified down to quintic in $\cos x$, then we don't want the root $x=0$ so I factored out $\cos x=1$ and removed it. Then I divided sum taken 3 at a time (obtained from coefficient of the biquadratic) and divided it by product to find the answer. But this took a lot of time and is a lengthy method. Please provide a shorter solution.
The question:


For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Letting $w=\frac z{1+z^2}$, note that if $z^5=1$ and $z\ne1$ then
$$w^2-w-1=\frac{-1-z-z^2-z^3-z^4}{(1+z^2)^2}=0.$$
Furthermore,
$$\frac{1/z}{1+(1/z)^2}=\frac z{1+z^2}.$$
Therefore,
$$\sum_{z^5=1\atop z\ne1}\frac z{1+z^2}=2\sum_{w^2-w-1=0}w=2,$$
so $z'=2-1-i=\sqrt2e^{7i\pi/4}$, and $(\sqrt2)^2+7=9$.
Edit1. Details about "the last two steps, i.e. the last two Sigma notations". Let $z_n:=e^{ni2\pi/5}$ and $w_n:=\frac{z_n}{1+z_n^2}.$ Then, the two numbers $w_1=w_4$ and $w_2=w_3$ are the roots of $w^2-w-1=0$, so their sum is $1$.
Edit2. The original question did not specify $z\ne1$. For $z=1$ we still have
$$\frac z{1+z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1+z^4}+\frac{z^3}{1+z}+\frac{z^4}{1+z^3}=2.$$This seems to indicate there should be a shorter solution.
Edit3. Here is how I discovered $w^2-w-1=0$: by definition of $w$, $z^2=\frac zw-1$, which allows to express also $z^3,z^4$ as linear combinations (involving $w$) of $z$ and $1$. Substituting in $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$ led to $\left(\frac1w-\frac1{w^2}-\frac1{w^3}\right)(w-z)=0$, and the result followed.
Edit4. Here is the
shorter solution
smelled in Edit2: assume $z^5=1$ and let $w_k:=\frac{z^k}{1+z^{2k}}$. Then,
$$\begin{align}w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4&=w_1+w_2+w_2+w_1\\&=2\left(\frac z{1+z^2}+\frac{z^2}{1+z^4}\right)\\&=2\,\frac{z(1+z^4)+z^2(1+z^2)}{(1+z^2)(1+z^4)}\\&=2,\end{align}$$
even if $z=1$.

Sorry, but I am not able to understand the last two steps, I mean the last two Sigma notations

Also could you please tell, what was your thought process behind writing w^2-w-1 like how could one think that like what made you think that...(Thanks for the short solution btw)

Neat. Nice substitution.

Woah, that's awesome

Let $~\alpha = 2i\pi/5,~$ and let $~w = e^{i\alpha}.~$ 
Then, the $~5~$ roots of $~z^5 = 1~$ are given by
$~\{ ~1, ~w, ~w^2, ~w^3, ~w^4 ~\}.~$

You have the trigonometric identities
$$\cos(2\theta) = \cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta) = 2\cos^2(\theta) - 1,$$
$$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta).$$
So, for any $~z = e^{i\theta}, ~: ~z^2 \neq -1,~$ you have that
$$\frac{z}{1 + z^2} = \frac{\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)}{1 + \cos(2\theta) + i\sin(2\theta)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)}
{2\cos^2(\theta) + 2i\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}$$
$$=\frac{\cos\theta) + i\sin(\theta)}{2\cos(\theta) ~~[ ~\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta) ~]}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2\cos(\theta)}.$$

Further, you have that
$$\frac{w^3}{1 + w^6} = \frac{1}{2\cos(3\alpha)} = \frac{1}{2\cos(2\alpha)}$$
and
$$\frac{w^4}{1 + w^8} = \frac{1}{2\cos(4\alpha)} = \frac{1}{2\cos(\alpha)}$$
Also,
$$\cos(\alpha) = \frac{w + w^4}{2}, ~~\cos(2\alpha) = \frac{w^2 + w^3}{2}.$$

Therefore,
$$\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{w^k}{1 + w^{2k}} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)} + \frac{1}{\cos(2\alpha)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{w + w^4} + \frac{2}{w^2 + w^3}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{[ ~2(w^2 + w^3) ~] + [ ~2(w + w^4) ~]}{(w + w^4)(w^2 + w^3)}$$
$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{2 [ ~w + w^2 + w^3 + w^4 ~]}{w + w^2 + w^3 + w^4} = \frac{1}{2} + 2.$$
Note
Since you know that $~\cos(\alpha) \neq \cos(\alpha/2) = -\cos(2\alpha),~$ you can deduce that $~\dfrac{w + w^4}{2} \neq - \dfrac{w^2 + w^3}{2} \implies (w + w^4) \neq -(w^2 + w^3).$
